# Determining the Probability of a Password

Tags: permutations, combinations

I create a 10 letter password by randomly mixing:
4 letters, from (A, B, C, D, or E) without repeats 
3 numbers, from (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5) without repeats
3 symbols, from (@, #, $, %, or *) without repeats

determine the probability that my password begins with A, has no two numbers next to each other, and includes the symbol *

Comment: I know you're new here, but common courtesy would dictate at least typing your answer in with proper punctuation. That is besides the fact that you should say when your problem comes from a homework (or a test), and that you should show some effort when asking about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The main formula here is $P(a)=\frac{C(A)}{C(\Omega)}$. $C()$ means count, so the formula can be written also as $\dfrac{\left|A\right|}{\left|\Omega\right|}$.

$C(\Omega)$: we have to choose 4 letters from 5, no return, then 3 numbers from 5, no return and 3 symbols from 5, again with no return. All of it can be mixed into 10 different place That is:
${5 \choose 4} * {5 \choose 3} * {5 \choose 3} * 10!$

$C(A)$: we need to choose 3 letters from 4, since A selected already. Then choose 3 numbers from 5 and 2 symbols from 4. This is :${4 \choose 3} * {5 \choose 3} * {4 \choose 2}$

All of this can be mixed into 10 place, under conditions: A must start and no two number next to each other. The first one is simply choose only $9!$ option, but the second one is a bit tricky. It can be solved as follows:

We need to choose 3 place to put there numbers. it is equivalent to choosing 4 "spaces" between the numbers. For example: --N--N--N (N denotes Number) can be written as $(2,2,2,0)$. Notate that "spaces" as $a_1...a_4$ we know that:

$\sum a_n=6$ (There is 9 place, 3 of them numbers)

$a_2$ and $a_3$ both > 0

We replace $a_n$ by $b_n$ as follows: $b_1=a_1,b_2=a_2-1,b_3=a_3-1, b_4=a_4$ and get:
$$\sum b_n = 4,b_n\ge0$$
The number of solutions for that is $9 \choose 4$ (won't be proven here) and then:

We choose what numbers, symbols and letters to use : ${4 \choose 3} * {5 \choose 3} * {4 \choose 2}$

We choose 3 place for numbers, and internal order of the numbers : ${9 \choose 4} * 3!$

We choose order for the other 6 elements (The first A is forced): $6!$

Total: ${4 \choose 3} * {5 \choose 3} * {4 \choose 2} * {9 \choose 4} * 3! * 6!$

Finally, we divide the results. We have:
$$\frac
{{4 \choose 3} * {5 \choose 3} * {4 \choose 2} * {9 \choose 4} * 3! * 6!}
{{5 \choose 4} * {5 \choose 3} * {5 \choose 3} * 10!}$$
Canceling $5 \choose 3$ and opening $n \choose k$ gives:
$$
\frac
{{\frac{4!}{3!1!}} * {\frac{4!}{2!2!}} * {\frac{9!}{5!4!}} * 3! * 6!}
{{\frac{5!}{4!1!}} * {\frac{5!}{3!2!}} * 10!}$$
It can be simplified to:
$$
\frac
{{\frac{1}{2!}} * {\frac{1}{5!}} * 6!}
{{\frac{5}{1}} * {\frac{5}{3!}} * 10}
=
\frac
{3*6}
{5*5*10}=
\frac{9}{125}$$

Comment: That seems like extremely odd notation - what is $C()$? Do you just mean a count? How about $\dfrac{\left|A\right|}{\left|\Omega\right|}$?

Comment: Yes, $C()$ is count. This is the notation I learned.